# Can't receive data from form

Tags: reactjs, forms, express, proxy, connection

The problem I currently have is that when I send my form data in React using axios or even without it I am unable to retrieve my data on the backend side using express. I am viewing the request received on the back end console but am unable to access it via code. React code is via Node on port 3000, Express on 3001. Application was created using create-react-app, here is a picture:[Problem](https://github.com/Averynder/cssd/issues/45)

Project Structure:

- cssd             -> Where I run npm start launching back end
- cssd/routes/     -> Where users.js is located with the routes to obtain code
- cssd/client/     -> Where i run npm start launching front end
- cssd/client/src/setupProxy.js -> where my proxy route is

I've already tried creating a setupProxy.js file as well as numerous get / post methods trying to receive the data and any of the info available on stack has been searched as well but if I've missed something please let me know. Even with a console.log at the base, i still can't receive it.

Within setupProxy:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/routes/*', 
        { target: "http://localhost:3001/" }
    ));
}
```

Within client's App.js / React:

```
render() {
    return (
        <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name"/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

handleSubmit(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var inputData = {name, email, message};
    fetch('/routes/users',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: inputData
        })
    alert("sent data");
    this.resetForm();
}
```

Within routes/users.js / Express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(
bodyParser.urlencoded({ // basically any extra characters
    extended: true
}),
bodyParser.json()
);

// Re-directs, ex entered in nothing, go to get
router.get("/routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 1 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data: ", name, email, message);
});

router.post("/routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 2 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data", name, email, message);
});

app.get("/routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 3 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data: ", name, email, message);
});

app.post("/routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 4 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data", name, email, message);
});

router.get("routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 5 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data: ", name, email, message);
});

router.post("routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 6 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data", name, email, message);
});

app.get("routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 7 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data: ", name, email, message);
});

app.post("routes/users", function(req, res) {
console.log("HERE 8 !");
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var message = req.body.message;
console.log("The data", name, email, message);
});

const port = 3000;
//console.log(`Back end is listening on port ${port}`);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Back end is listening on port ${port}`));

module.exports = router;
```

The expected results should be that I receive a console.log from one of the functions and can then work with my code from there but I'm just unable to get any of them to be called. Only thing shown in the console is on the back-end side receiving the request

Comment: How are your inputs working without an onChange handler?

The React way would be to update state based on an onChange handler.  Can you console.log the inputData before you send it from the client?  I'm also unfamiliar with your proxy library, but doesn't middleware hit after the route is hit?

Comment: @Mark I honnestly have no idea and one isn't included in the code at the moment. I'm new to react and any code to try out would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all proxying from the server as this is only if you are serving the client and server from the same host and port.  So make sure your app.listen is on a different port than your client like so.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listnening on ${port}`));
```

Is this app set up with Create React App?  If so you can add a proxy to the package.json of the client (React)

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Comment: I get a Reference Error when I try to run the Express code for app.use. It says proxy is undefined. Downloaded npm install express-http-proxy --save. Still no luck

Comment: Downloaded npm install express-http-proxy --save. and imported the var, as

    var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
    app.use(
 bodyParser.urlencoded({ // basically any extra characters
  extended: true
 }),
 bodyParser.json(),
 '/routes/*', proxy({ target: "http://localhost:3001/" })
    );
says type error Router.use requires a middleware function but got a string

Comment: Can you confirm if this is a create-react-app project or not?  Are you serving your client and server from the same port?

Comment: Can you post your app.listen so we can see what port your server is running from?  If it is create-react-app are you running from the default port through webpack?

Comment: If you are using different ports for your client and server then you want to change your package.json in your client (React project) to have a 'proxy' property

    "proxy": "http://localhost:{the port you specified in app.listen}"

Comment: I've done that and still no luck.
sure like a screen shot from the place where it says problem in the Q or do you want me to type it out? Server is running on port 3001 and react on 3000 but I have an app.listen on 3000 in the users.js code on backend, it's at the end of the code in the Q

Comment: Change the port on the backend to be different from the front end.  Check out my updated example.

Comment: Just updated to 3002, didn't go with 5000 but I've got a console.log of HERE4. Says all data is undefined though

Answer (score 0):

Create react app uses webpack dev server to serve your app to the browser. You can use a proxy from your client to achieve want you want.

In your package.json of your react app, add `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`

Here is more info about this from the create react app [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#docsNav).

Your backend code does not need any changes to make this work, in fact I would even remove all proxy setup code in your backend. Only thing needed is to add this one setting in your react app package.json.

Comment: Tried, and no luck

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? Also, after adding this setting, did you restart the client server?

Comment: yes I did do it, and you mean all the links I've used thus far, they won't fit in the comments section

Comment: {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3002",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}

Comment: Did that from Mark's solution, I got into the the console. "Here4" but can't retrieve the data